# In Xamarin Forms how to call MainActivity's method or get MainActivity's 'Window' from another class?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to hide software buttons when enter text to entry is done. When user put finger outside keyboard, this method is invoked:

```
 public override void OnUserInteraction()
        {
            base.OnUserInteraction();
            HideSoftwareMenuBars();
        }
```

That works perfectly:

```
 private void HideSoftwareMenuBars()
        {
            try
            {
                int uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
                this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
            }
            catch (System.Exception Ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

But there is no method in MainActivity.cs to override that is being called when user press "enter" key on keyboard. I have overridden more than 200 methods to check it. Then in Xamarin.Forms in code behind I have event:

```
private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<ISoftwareButtons>().HideSoftwareMenuBars();
        }
```

Then by calling dependency interface, here I have 2 errors:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SoftwareButtonsHandler))]
namespace Channel.Droid.DependencyHandlers
{
    public class SoftwareButtonsHandler
    {
        private void HideSoftwareMenuBars()
        {
            try
            {
                int uiOptions = (int) Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
                uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
                this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
            }
            catch (System.Exception Ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that "Window.Devorview" has errors:

> "Abstract base class for a top-level window look and behaviour policy.
>   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Window.DecorView;"

and "this.Window"

> "SoftwareButtonsHandler' does not contain definition for 'Window' and
>   no accessible extension method 'Window' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'SoftwareButtonsHandler' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?"

Is there a way to call MainActivity.cs's method from another class or get necessary "Window" in dependency handler (that is accessible only in MainActivity.cs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a static reference to MainActivity that will be accessible everywhere, or you may use CurrentActivity plugin.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `MainActivityInstance` in `MainActivity` and set it like `MainActivityInstance = this` in `OnCreate`:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity MainActivityInstance { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        MainActivityInstance = this;

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Then you can get the MainActivity in dependency interface:

```
public class SoftwareButtonsHandler : ISoftwareButtons
{

    void ISoftwareButtons.HideSoftwareMenuBars()
    {
        try
        {
            int uiOptions = (int)MainActivity.MainActivityInstance.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
            uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
            uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation;
            uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen;
            uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
            uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
            uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
            uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
            MainActivity.MainActivityInstance.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
        }
        catch (System.Exception Ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant get the reference to the MainActivity public static object.  Do I need to add a Using directive, or somehow add a dependency to it?  This is in a cross platform Forms project.